# how to properly promote Entity Framework code-first migrations into production?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

In my ASP.NET EF 6 app, I have the following Configuration:

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<Gcim.Management.Module.BusinessObjects.ManagementDbContext>
    {
        public Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
        }

        protected override void Seed(Gcim.Management.Module.BusinessObjects.ManagementDbContext context)
        {

        }
    }
```

In my project, I have EF code-first migrations enabled.
I'm able to run add-migration, as well as update-database from the VS Package Manager prompt.
However, when my entities change, adding a migration, and updating database only works in dev environment.
When I publish my ASP.NET project, install it on production IIS, and run, I still get this error:

```
The model backing the 'ManagementDbContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269).
```

What else do I need to do in order to force the incremental DB changes in production, without data loss?

Comment: What is your deployment procedure? You can invoke a migration with `migrate.exe` - we've usually done this as part of the deployment in our continuous integration setup (e.g TeamCity, Jenkins, TFS). How you deploy your application will inform how you perform the migration alongside it.

Comment: I simply unzip the published package under C:\inetroot\www\MyAppName folder. What files will migrate.exe need in order to perform the migrations? In the VS, the C# migration files are part of the project, but, after the project is published, they are not part of the app package. In your case, when you run migrate.exe, what do you provide as a parameter, to explain what needs to be migrated?

Comment: You can find documentation on migrate.exe here `https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj618307.aspx` We configured the build step to target the most recent migration in the directory. Our build server had access to the full source code via version control, so it had the migration files available to it when it ran. In your case, since you're doing everything by hand, you'll need to run the migration targeting your production environment right before you unzip. I would suggest using a build/deploy solution like Jenkins (free!), TFS or TeamCity, as it makes this process much stronger

Comment: yep - found it, read it, ran it - works well. be happy to accept as the answer.  thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can execute a given migration file against a given environment (in this case, your production environment) by using the `migrate.exe` application included as part of the Entity Framework nuget package. You'll need to execute your latest migration against your production environment before publishing your web application - once this has been done, the newly deployed application will work correctly.

You do this by specifying the connection string and .dll containing the migration class(es), as well as possibly a specific migration. For example:

`Migrate.exe Gcim.Management.Module.BusinessObjects.dll /connectionString="Data Source=[YourProductionDatabase];Initial Catalog=[YourTable];Integrated Security=SSPI" /connectionProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" /targetMigration="[NameofYourMigration]"`

Documentation on `migrate.exe` can be found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj618307.aspx